# Iterate through get-QADGroup for get-QADUser

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to Iterate through each line of $group in $user.  I believe that I should be using an array but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Here are the basics of what I'm trying to do.

```
$group = get-qadgroup -sizelimit 20 | select name

$user = Get-QADuser -memberof $group | %{
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    MemberOf = $group
    Name = $_.Name
    FirstName = $_.Firstname
    LastName = $_.Lastname
    AccountIsDisabled = $_.AccountIsDisabled
    DN = $_.DN
  }
}
$user | Select MemberOf, Name, FirstName, LastName, AccountIsDisabled, DN
```

Edit: Very sorry, I should add that I am only able to use get-QADGroup and get-QADUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing it a little backwards. I don't use the Quest cmdlets, but using the standard ActiveDirectory cmdlets you could do:

```
$Group = Get-ADGroup <name> -prop Members
$Members = $Group.Members | ForEach{
    $User = Get-ADUser $_
    [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        'First Name' = $User.givenName
        'Last Name' = $User.sn
        'Group' = $Group.Name
        'Account Enabled' = $user.enabled
        'Distinguished Name' = $User.dn
    }
}
```

Then $Members would contain an array of objects as you described in your question. If you wanted more than group, well, I'm not sure why you would want that, and how you would want to manage the data. Is this just going to be a massive CSV dump to show all users and the groups that they belong to or something?

Now that I think of it, that might throw errors on group members that are groups, and not users, but I suppose you could put that into a try/catch or something to avoid issues there.

**Edit:** Ok, using Get-QADUser:

```
Get-QADUser -ShowProgress -Activity 'Retrieving all domain users' -ProgressThreshold 0 -SizeLimit 0 | ForEach{
    $User = $_
    $User.MemberOf | ForEach{
        [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
            'First Name' = $User.givenName
            'Last Name' = $User.sn
            'Group' = $_
            'Account Enabled' = $user.enabled
            'Distinguished Name' = $User.dn
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV "C:\Path\To\AllUsersGroups.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: Very sorry, I should add that I am only able to use get-QADGroup and get-QADUser.

Comment: I'm trying to query all of our AD and get a csv doc that shows users and the assigned groups.  I need it to be pivotable in Excel.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Really? You are able to install third party cmdlets, but not the official sanctioned cmdlets from MS?

Comment: OK fine, here. That gets all users, and then outputs your desired object for each group they are a member of. Since Get-QADUser didn't document on the web what it's output is I have to assume it will have similar properties to the standard Get-ADUser cmdlet.